# Page Benchmarking tool to measure average response time

Tags: javascript, browser, benchmarking

I want to measure the avg response time over 'n' reloads of a URL...I know extensions which do it for a single load...to get cumulative statistics is there any other tool/extension? (There is one from google - Page Benchmarker, but that doesn't seem to be working with the latest version of chrome) If not, is it possible using selenium or do I have to write an extension of my own by tweaking the extensions which measure values for a single load..